# iOS: CGRectMake doesn't change position of a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, cgrectmake

I've created a label via storyboard. The order is like this:
View -> Scroll View -> Bunch of labels.

Here is the text output I want to achieve:
2 December <30 days left>

the <> enclosed text is in smaller letters an in a different UI Label.

Since the month name is dynamic and the width changes I've tried using CGRectMake to alter the position of the <> enclosed text.
But it isn't working. I tried changing the parameters of the function but the label stays put. It doesn't move from its initial position set in storyboard.

```
label_days_left.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 100, 99);
```

EDIT:

```
- (void) alignDaysLeft{
    //code to align the label just after the match date
    CGFloat dateLabelWidth = [label_date.text sizeWithFont:label_date.font].width;
    CGFloat dateLabelHeight = [label_date.text sizeWithFont:label_date.font].height;
    CGFloat someGap = 0;
    CGFloat daysLeftX = label_date.frame.origin.x + dateLabelWidth + someGap;
    CGFloat daysLeftY = label_date.frame.origin.y;
    [label_date sizeToFit];
    //label_days_left.frame = CGRectMake(daysLeftX, daysLeftY, 100, dateLabelHeight);
    label_days_left.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 100, 99);
    label_days_left.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lolo"];
    NSLog(@"date width - %f", daysLeftX);

}
```

label_date is the variable which contains the month and day.
label_days_left is the label variable which I am trying to place next to the month.

EDIT 2:
[image: Frames]

EDIT 3:
I created a new project.
Dragged a label on the view.
Created an outlet.
Synthesized it.

And used the following code to move it -

```
[labia setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 5, 99)];
```

It didn't work. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: Where are you placing this code? Is it inside a view controller delegate method?

Comment: It is in "appname_timeViewController.m" file. I'm calling it in a custom function.

Comment: Please share a bit more of your code with us. Whenever you acutally change the frame of a UIView then it changes. There must be somewhere else that either changes it back to its original values or causes that label_days_left is not really connected to the view object. Or something else.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've added the function which is using 'CGRectMake'.

Comment: Does the label change its text to "lolo"? Did you try checking that label_days_left is not ni? What is the frame of label_days_left at the end of this method?

Comment: @HermannKlecker Yes, the label changes to "lolo".
I don't know the answer to your other question.

Comment: Well, then go for it. "NSLog (@"%@",label_days_left);" should give you the frame.

Comment: @HermannKlecker you are right, the frame is " frame = (50 10; 100 99)". Surprisingly on the screen, the label doesn't move.

Comment: So when and where is this mehtod called? Tip: When haveing problems understanding frames, coordinates, view hierarchy and the works it helps me sometimes to set the background value of the view programmatically to some bright colour like green or yellow or red or so. Sometimes you often see better on the screen how the views are really laid out.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've added a photo with colored bg. It shows the same position for the label.

Comment: Can you change any of the other view's frames? Again, when in the view's life cycle is it called? May there be something executed later that is changing the frame back to its original value?

Comment: @HermannKlecker I tried changing the position of another label. It didn't work.
I'm getting the JSON data from nw, updating the labels and then calling this method to position the label.

Comment: Tried using self.label_days_left.frame =...?

Comment: @HM1 self doesn't make any difference. Apparently the value for frame is changed. However the output is still the same. 
I can call 'label_days_left.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 100, 99);' anywhere right? Or is there supposed to be a certain method which can call it?

Comment: I believe you can call it anywhere in the ViewController its defined in. It's good practice to use self.blabla for instance variables. Is label_days_left an IBOutlet and correctly tied to its corresponding component in IB? Next, I would NSLog its frame before and after setting it to see if at least the frame is being changed.

Comment: @HM1 Yeah, the IBOutlet is corretly connected, I can change the value of the text. I did NSLog the frame, the value is getting changed to "frame = (50 10; 100 99)" but the label doesn't move.

Comment: Well from the code posted it's all correct. I would step through the code line by line and see if the view is updating or not or if another method is getting called and reseting it. Other thoughts would be to create a new project with only a single label and try moving it. Then see what's different in your current project.

Comment: @HM1 I created a new project with a single label, it didn't work.
I've outlined all the steps I've did in the edit. Please take a look at it. It only takes the constraint from the storyboard.

Comment: @HermannKlecker the problem was auto layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have AutoLayout turned on? If so then that might be your problem, as you are not supposed to worry about setting the frame with AutoLayout, and instead set constraints.

Comment: You sir, are awesome! I didn't know anything about Autolayout. Problem solved! But will turning it off create any problem?

Comment: @Pritesh depends if you're using it to support different screen sizes and layouts. You can also use autosizing or do it in code to support different screens. Check out this tutorial (part 1 & 2) for more info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: @PriteshDesai turning it off should not cause any problems if you were not really utilizing it before, but you should double check just to be sure. I personally find it easier to work without it, but there are situations where it could be useful.

Comment: This helped me, even though I had not set any constraints on any of the elements in my view. For some reason setting the frame of a UILabel had no effect until I turned off AutoLayout in the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",label_date.text]
UIFont *yourFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
CGSize stringBoundingBox = [someString sizeWithFont:yourFont];
[label_days_left setFrame:CGRectMake(label_days_left.frame.origin.x, 10, stringBoundingBox.width, 99)];
[label_days_left setText:someString];
```

Pls try this once....

Comment: Hi Vijay, I tried your code, it isn't working. I then created a new project with a single label, still it didn't work. I've outlined all the steps I've did in the edit. Please take a look at it. It only takes the constraint from the storyboard. Am I missing any step?